# Extract a specific line from excel containing multiple lines with Specfic String

Tags: excel, extract

I have an excel column which contains data but each cell contains data in multiple lines. Some of the lines are empty and some of the lines are filled. Now I want to extract only that line which contain a specific word e.g "shipping". Many thanks for everybody in advance.

Best Regards

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share a ***specific* problem** after trying to solve it on their own. See "[ask]", and also the [help/on-topic] for more information about what's on topic on this site.  If you have a *specific* problem with a certain section of your code, you can [edit] your post to share an **[mcve]** as well as sample data and some background info.  Here are some  [tips](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the site's top user. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IF(ISERR(FIND("shipping",LOWER(B1))),0,FIND("shipping",LOWER(B1)))
```

The "IF(ISERR())" eliminates any ugly '#VALUE!' error messages
The "LOWER()" makes sure mixed case words aren't overlooked

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWivS.png)